# Is there any way to fine-tune the mouse sensitivity?

Tags: pc, bioshock-infinite

With mouse acceleration on, the mouse is too sensitive, even at the lowest setting.

With mouse acceleration off, the mouse is not nearly sensitive enough at the lowest setting, but way too sensitive at the next higher setting.

Is there some configuration file I can edit?  This is annoying me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [PC Gaming Wiki, "BioShock Infinite - Mouse speed slider tweak" article](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/BioShock_Infinite#Mouse_speed_slider_tweak):

#### Mouse slider tweak

This fix will modify in-game slider and give better control.

- Navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\BioShock Infinite\XGame\Config\`.
- Locate and open file `XUserOptions` in text editor (notepad for example).
- Locate lines `MinMouseLookSensitivity=0.100000` and `MaxMouseLookSensitivity=4.000000` and change values to your taste. Values 0.05 for MinMouse and 0.5 for MaxMouse works OK
- Start the game and set your desired sensitivity via slider.

#### Finer grained mouse sensitivity

This fix will let you set exact sensitivity values.

- Navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\BioShock Infinite\XGame\Config\`.
- Locate and open file `XUserOptions` in text editor.
- Locate line `MouseLookSensitivity` and set to desired value. This value has the same effect as the `MouseSensitivity` string used in other Unreal Engine titles.